# How to use a UDF defined in a sub-module in pySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to use a PySpark UDF defined in a sub-module `module.foo` which I have added to my `SparkContext`. When I try, PySpark throws a `ModuleNotFoundError` for the *main* module `module`.

If I move the submodule out of the main module it is working as expected but I would prefer to keep the structure as it is.

Any idea ?

Precisely, the structure of my code is

```
project/
|- main.py
|- module/
   |- __init__.py
   |- foo.py
```

**main.py**

```py
import module.foo
spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName(appName) \
            .config(conf=sConf) \
            .enableHiveSupport() \
            .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.addPyFile('some_path/project/module/foo.py')

df = module.foo.bar(spark)
```

**foo.py**

```py
from pyspark.sql.types      import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions  import udf

def hello():
    return "Hello World"

def bar(spark):
    hello_udf = udf(hello, StringType())
    df = (spark.sql('SELECT * FROM pokemons')
               .withColumn('hello', hello_udf()))
    return df.toPandas()
```

The error I have is

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a local function, like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types      import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions  import udf

def bar(spark):
    def hello():
        return "Hello World"

    hello_udf = udf(hello, StringType())
    df = (spark.sql('SELECT * FROM pokemons')
               .withColumn('hello', hello_udf()))
    return df.toPandas()
```

Many people have opinions about this issue, because it is a 'now and then' bug.

What's actually happening is when you call `bar` **from main.py**, you are actually running the function `module.foo.bar`.

Therefore, when you attempt to register the function `hello` as a udf, you are actually registering the function hello *relative to the entry point*.

This is why if you copy your code into `main.py` it will run fine.

```
- main.py
-- def hello <-- the absolute path of hello relative to main is 'hello' -> WORKS OK

- foo.py
-- def hello <-- when running from foo.py, abs path is hello -> WORKS OK.
             <-- when running from main.py, abs path is foo.hello -> ModuleNotFoundError.
```

Since `foo.hello` is not registered on the worker, this will result in an error.

When you create a local function, like:

```
def foo():
    def tmp(): # <-- This is a local function, so it has no module path, so it works.
        ...
```

This seems to be a bug in pyspark, honestly.

Comment: Hello @Doug, I'm having this same error using databricks-connect, but on an external module I have installed in my virtual env (sklearn-pmml-model). I can use the module just fine, but the problem occurs when I create a UDF that uses said module. Any ideas? Sorry, I don't even know where to post this

Comment: @itscarlayall you need to use https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/cluster-libraries.html for that; no matter how you structure your UDF, if the function *and all its dependencies* is not defined on the worker, your UDF will fail. Installing something in your virtualenv doesn't work; databricks flat out doesn't support that using databricks connect I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd been trying for hours and nothing seemed to work, now I could finally execute it without errors. Just so I understand, is this because the UDF launched through databricks-connect sends the execution steps into the cluster driver, so the libraries need to be installed there as well? Thanks again,

Comment: @itscarlayall Cluster libraries are installed on the driver and all worker nodes; but UDFs are executed on the workers; the command is serialized sent to the workers... so basically yes, but when you are using connect, your local machine *is* the driver. Just think of UDFs as running on the worker nodes, each of which have their own venv; what you need to do is ensure they can execute the UDF in isolation. If you have more questions or trouble, feel free to post an actual question and you can tag me in a comment on it.

Comment: @Doug this answer saved my day! I had the same issue for a pandas_udf definition and nothing helped (I tried to add the module to the spark context etc.). Defining the subfunctions locally in the pandas udf function also helped here.

Comment: @Doug, would you please take a look at this question and guide me? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77837238/6640504

Answer (score 0):

the reason you get ModuleNotFoundError, is because you add foo.py, without adding module package(with **init**.py), so when you try import module.*(not matter what u try to import from module), it cannot find module package.

you should zip all your project, when main.py and module package will be at the first, and then addPyFiles(dep.zip).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by zipping the files in the project. Could you go into more detail?