# moduleNotFoundError in Pyspark running with Spark-Submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an ETL code which has been written with Pyspark. I have two bash scripts to run the code. When I use this script, it's run without any problems:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 cd /root/Desktop/project
 rm etl.zip
 zip -r ./etl.zip * -x logs/\*
/u01/spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.driver.host=x.x.x.x --conf spark.driver.memory=28g --conf spark.executor.memory=24g --conf spark.rpc.message.maxSize=1024 --conf spark.rpc.askTimeout=600s --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=36000 --driver-class-path ojdbc8.jar  --files config.json,basic_tables_config.json --py-files etl.zip project_main.py
```

But, when I use this scrip, I receive **moduleNotFoundError**. One of the python file is not found.

```
 #!/bin/bash


 cd /root/Desktop/project
 rm etl.zip
 zip -r ./etl.zip * -x logs/\*
 /u01/spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.driver.host=x.x.x.x --conf spark.driver.memory=28g --conf spark.executor.memory=24g  --driver-class-path ojdbc8.jar --files config.json,basic_tables_config.json --py-files etl.zip project_main.py
```

I checked two scripts, first one had these parameters:

```
   --conf spark.rpc.message.maxSize=1024 --conf spark.rpc.askTimeout=600s --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=36000
```

Would you please guide me what is wrong with the second script?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Add a comma between your .json files as in the first script, and it would be fine. Because right now its missing: `...--files config.json basic_tables_config.json...`

Comment: @mazaneicha, I have add that, I just wrote wrong here. Thank you to say that.

Comment: Now you have a space after comma which should be removed: `--files config.json, basic_tables_config.json`. Alternatively, you can enclose the whole argument in double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show me the logs?

I have encountered similar issues and need to add the following configurations

```bash
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/user/anaconda3/envs/env2/bin/python3.6
--conf spark.pyspark.driver.python=/home/user/anaconda3/envs/env2/bin/python3.6
```